# Docker-compose Error

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Currently, I have set up 'nginx' and 'php-fpm' using 'docker-compose' like below. Nginx connects to php:9000, however, web server gives me 502 Bad Gateway error. I assume docker-compose command didn't link nginx and php-fpm correctly.

Any advice or suggestion? Thanks in advance.

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: wb/truckup-nginx:latest # private repo
    #network_mode: 'bridge'
    depends_on:
      - php
    volumes_from:
      - php
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
    links:
      - php
  php:
    container_name: php
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    image: wb/truckup-app:0.1 # private repo
    #environment:
      #MYSQL_HOST: mysql
      #MYSQL_USER: root
      #MYSQL_PASSWORD: passme
      #MYSQL_DATABASE: database
    #데이터 볼륨 컨테이너 안의 데이터 볼륨 디렉터리에 접근가능
    volumes:
      - /home/*:/home/*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your compose-file is correct. To recheck link command run probaly or not. You can `exec` to your nginx container

`docker exec -it nginx bash`

and ping to php container using

```
ping php
```

if everything is ok, recheck your image.

Comment: My problem was that the port I am using was not properly open. Thank you for the answer.